# searching a wsgi testing plugin in python

Tags: python, testing, httpwebrequest, wsgi

i was wondering what you'r using to test your python wsgi apps and which one is the most updated and easiest to setup.

im on appengine python and i would like to start writing tests for my handlers.

i've see [gaeunit](http://code.google.com/p/gaeunit/) and [nose-gae](http://code.google.com/p/nose-gae/) and if there are some more out there and what you think about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [webtest](http://pythonpaste.org/webtest) with nose-gae.  While it doesn't emulate javascript, it is a great way to exercise each handler in your app, and has nice support for forms too.

For more detail testing of each edge case, I would factor our utilities / model related logic from the handlers and write tests for those separately.  But it is nice to have some end to end tests, and webtest works great for that.

Comment: yes this is what i needed. do you have an idea if the blobstore is supported like the datastore?  
cant find out if it is and im getting errors if i try to test an upload.